# Setting up local environment for Nest + TypeORM + MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to write a script that will spin up a docker container MySQL DB that can connect with my Nest.JS API. The goal is to use this across multiple people for easy setup of environment.
I plan to run

```
nest start --watch
```

will start the API. I am just struggling with setting up/connecting to the DB.

I have a `docker-compose.yml` that looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:

   # MySQL database
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: db
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_name
```

and my databaseProvider looks like :

```
export const databaseProviders = [
  {
    provide: DATABASE_CONNECTION,
    useFactory: async () => await createConnection({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      database: 'db_name',
      entities: [
          __dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}',
      ],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
  },
];
```

I get the error :

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: have you tried it with a mysql client or workbench.

Comment: use "db" instead of "localhost".